# Django throwing Improperly Configured error whatever I do

Tags: python, django, csv, import

I've been trying to figure out how to export my db as a csv file in a certain format (doing the data dump to JSON and converting to csv won't work or will take too long to do). Currently I have a script that just iterates through each of the objects and writes out the relevant information to a file. However, for some strange reason, Django complains by throwing:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "csv_export.py", line 4, in <module>
 from models import Patient, Nurse, Doctor, HospitalAdmin
 File "/home/ian/Documents/swen261/master_project/HealthNet/main_site/models.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from django.middleware.csrf import rotate_token
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 14, in <module>
from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/cache.py", line 26, in <module>
from django.core.cache import caches
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/cache/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
if DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS not in settings.CACHES:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Here is the script:

```
# exports db as a csv file

import sys, os, django
sys.path.append('~/Documents/swen261/masterProject/HealthNet/main_site/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'main_site.settings'
django.setup()
from models import Patient, Nurse, Doctor, HospitalAdmin

print("Starting DB export script...\n")

print("Creating csv file 'csv_output.csv'...\n")
with open('csv_output.csv', 'w+') as file:
    print("Writing out Patients...\n")
# formatting got a little screwed here, the rest below this should be indented.
for p in Patient.objects.all():
    file.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\n"
               % ("Patient", p.user.username, p.user.password, p.user.first_name, p.user.last_name, p.hospital.name, p.insurance_provider, p.insurance_id, "nil"))
print("Writing out Doctors...\n")
for d in Doctor.objects.all():
    file.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\n"
               % ("Doctor", d.user.username, d.user.password, d.user.first_name, d.user.last_name, d.hospital.name, "nil","nil","nil"))
print("Writing out Nurses...\n")
for n in Nurse.objects.all():
    file.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\n"
               % ("Nurse", n.user.username, n.user.password, n.user.first_name, n.user.last_name, n.hospital.name, "nil", "nil", "nil"))
print("Writing out Hospital Admins...\n")
for ha in HospitalAdmin.objects.all():
    file.write("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,\n"
               % ("HospitalAdmin", ha.user.username, ha.user.password, ha.user.first_name, ha.user.last_name, ha.hospital.name, "nil", "nil", "nil"))

 print("Finished creating csv.\n")
```

[image: The directory structure. And the template thing is a bug with pycharm.]

I'm not sure why it is doing this or how to fix it. The problem seems to be in the imports, even though I can legally do it in the views files. Everyone else with the same problem seems to be getting it a different way and I haven't been able to figure it out based on their answers.

Comment: buehler? I tried changing things up and it still throws improperly configured errors all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the top of your module (adjust the path to the right one for your project as well as 'settings')

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append('/path/to/your/django/app')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
from django.conf import settings
django.setup()
```

Comment: I tried it and nothing changed. Apparently its just the line 'from models import ...' Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to call `django.setup()` as well as the above.

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli So I tried that and now its throwing a no module named settings error at the 'django.setup()' line'

Comment: @Ian you need to adjust 'settings' with the path of your settings, eg. 'main_site.settings'

Comment: import sys, os, django
     sys.path.append('~/Documents/swen261/masterProject/HealthNet/main_site/')
     os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'main_site.settings'
    django.setup()
    from models import Patient, Nurse, Doctor, HospitalAdmin
Thats still throwing an error. main_site settings does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
import sys, os, django
sys.path.append('~/Documents/swen261/masterProject/HealthNet/main_site/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'main_site.settings'
```

to this:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/swen261/masterProject/HealthNet')))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'HealthNet.settings'
import django
```

the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env var needs to be an importable path. This should be done before you import django.

Comment: So that changes the error to this....   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv_export.py", line 10, in <module>
    from models import Patient, Nurse, Doctor, HospitalAdmin, Hospital
  ....
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Unable to detect the app label for model "Hospital." Ensure that its module, "models", is located inside an installed app.

Comment: Can you update your question with the directory structure of your app?

Comment: I updated the answer to account for your directory structure (and added a missing `os.path.expanduser` call).

Comment: Still getting this ... File "csv_export.py", line 10, in <module>
    from models import Patient, Nurse, Doctor, HospitalAdmin, Hospital
  File "/home/ian/Documents/swen261/master_project/HealthNet/main_site/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Hospital(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 131, in __new__
    'app.' % (new_class.__name__, model_module.__name__)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Unable to detect the app label for model "Hospital." Ensure that its module, "models", is located inside an installed app.

Comment: which leads me to think that its an error in settings.py, but I checked and main_site is in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: That is probably because you need to do `from main_site.models import ...` (or `from .models import` but that's will not work if you're going to execute the csv_export module directly).  Remember, only the top `HealthNet` is in your path, all imports must start from there (or be relative).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97130/discussion-between-ian-and-thebjorn).

Comment: Taking another look at your directory structure, it looks like your source files are inside your templates directory...
At the top-level there should be: your project folder, your app folder and your templates folder (and files like manage.py and requirements.txt)
project folder = the inner HealthNet folder, containing settings.py
app folder = your main_site folder, which should have your source files.
files that should be run as their own modules should probably reside in a tasks folder at top level. You'll save yourself some headaches if the tasks folder does not have an init.py file.